# lock seat for a session in mysql

Tags: codeigniter

For a travel website,I have 4 people who can travel at a time in a cab.When a user selects a seat it should be locked for him till his session expires.As i am just updating a field 'availability' for every user who selects that cab,I cannot use LOCK which works with a row.How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a same row in a table to keep the booked seat count. Get a lock on the row before going to update query. So that you can force the second user to wait for the lock until the seat count is updated by the first user.

Comment: Ya thats exactly wat im doing.I am decrementing 'availability' but if session expires 'availability' should be incremented.A trigger would increase the server load drastically.

Comment: Yes i got the problem. Do you use the session table? In that case you can keep the session id in the above table for the unfinished bookings. So that when the next booking request come, if there is any unconfirmed request you can check the last access time for the session id in the session table if that expired already. In that can use the seat.